# What is the best practice for building docker images for a Haskel web app

Tags: docker, haskell

I have a haskell web app that uses postgresql-simple, which require `libpq`.

I use stack for building the project on Mac

What is the best practice for building a Docker image for running a haskell web app? Such that:

1. I can use multi-staging build to include only the executable and the necessary dependencies in the final image
2. If I make changes to the code, rebuilding the image would not have to compile the packages again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack has built in support for both building with Docker, and for creating Docker images. The former can be turned on with the `--docker` command line flag (or modifications to `stack.yaml`), and the latter can be performed with the `stack image container` command. I use this for a number of websites.

Alternatively, you can also use multistage Docker files for this. One of my coworkers, Deni Bertovic, [wrote a blog post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/12/building-haskell-apps-with-docker) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was actually following that post to do multistage build, but it doesn't say about postgres. I wonder what dependencies needs to install on `fpco/pid1` to use `postgres-simple`